# Game Center Send and Receive Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multiplayer, game-center

I bought this book and got its source code from:
http://apress.com/book/downloadfile/4652

You can also download the source code without buying. I took the GameKitHelper class form it and included it in my game as I am trying to add game center multiplayer.

I am now trying to send and receive data but it crashes when I run it. Using that class, I call the send/receive data by using:

```
GameKitHelper *gkHelper = [GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper];
```

send:

```
[gkHelper sendDataToAllPlayers:(void *)data length:(NSUInteger)length];
```

Receive:

```
[gkHelper match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID];
```

But what variables to I enter? What match? gkHelper.currentMatch? The only data I want to send is an integer, the score, I also want to receive this, so each player sees one another scores. Do I need to make this integer into an NSData value? What playerID?

If someone could shed some light I would appreciate it, thanks.